# gson array deserialization with extra variables

Tags: android, arrays, json, arraylist, gson

I am not sure if this is a possible duplicate but I couldn't find a similar problem.

Currently, I am trying to retrieve an array from the API my company works with.
Since I retrieve all this data from the API I also get a status message back which consists of a String success or String error.
I am using Gson and Retrofit to retrieve and deserialize the JSON data.

This works with every Object but now I need to make an Object which is also an array.

The json output retrieved from API.

```
{
   "0":{
      "first_name":"Menno",
      "avatar":"[avatar here]",
      "updated_at":"2017-04-08 11:17:35",
      "id":"[id here]"
   },
   "1":{
      "first_name":"Team",
      "avatar":"[avatar here]",
      "updated_at":"2017-11-01 11:00:18",
      "id":"[id here]"
   },
   "success":"retrieve_common_connections_success"
}
```

As you can see the json starts with indexing the array and ends with a success message.

The class used to deserialize the JSON.

```
public class GetCommonConnections extends ArrayList<Connection> {
    public String getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(String success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public String getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(String error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    @SerializedName("success")
    private String success = "";
    @SerializedName("error")
    private String error = "";

}
```

I also get the error: *D/Error: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $*

Which means gson expects to start with an array but it starts with an object.
I am kind of lost on how this works and would like to know if any of you have a solution.

**EDIT**

Connection class.

```
public class Connection {
    private String first_name;
    private String avatar;
    private String updated_at;
    private int id;

    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public String getAvatar() {
        return avatar;
    }

    public void setAvatar(String avatar) {
        this.avatar = avatar;
    }

    public String getUpdated_at() {
        return updated_at;
    }

    public void setUpdated_at(String updated_at) {
        this.updated_at = updated_at;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And also the interface used.

```
public interface IGetCommonConnections {
    @POST(PostInterfaceMain.POST_URL)
    Call<CommonConnections> getCommonConnections(
            @Body PostConnections body
            );
}
```

Method used to call the API

```
public static void getCommonConnections(int resourceID, final CustomCallbackHandler callback)
    {
        PostConnections body = new PostConnections();
        body.setResourceID(resourceID);
        body.setAction("resource_get_common_connections");

        IGetCommonConnections taskService = ServiceGenerator.createService(IGetCommonConnections.class);
        Call<CommonConnections> call = taskService.getCommonConnections(body);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<CommonConnections>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CommonConnections> call, Response<CommonConnections> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "CommonConnections succesfully retrieved!");
                    callback.setArg(response.body());
                    callback.run();
                } else {
                    // error response, no access to resource?
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CommonConnections> call, Throwable t) {
                // something went completely south (like no internet connection)
                Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: you want to convert obj to json ?

Comment: you have to use `Map`, `List` only works when you have `[` not `{`

Comment: Could you add your retrofit method to call API? and Connection class to

Comment: Will do @FarshidABZ, Saurabh what exactly do you mean by that? Amit I want to convert the json to a Java Object.

Comment: Try to call :  Call<List<CommonConnections>> getCommonConnections(...);

Comment: The json is not formatted as an array. "0", "1," are member objects, not items inside a json array. Check if you have copied it correctly.

Comment: @Juan Ah I see but how could I deserialize those without having to create a class with 1000s of variables? Since the API can give me a lot more connections then only 2.

Comment: Do you have access to who is providing the data because if it really is being served like this, it seems to be wrongly structed. If the ojbect can have unlimited menbers, then I don't think Gson can help and you will have to parse the result item by item.

Comment: Sort of discovering what has come as a response.

Comment: @Juan that's what I thought aswell, the API is outsourced which does work on the IOS app made by the outsourced company... It seems I am out of luck then. I'll try to discuss it with them.

Comment: @Mennolp Take a look at the answer. Does it help you?

Comment: @HrishikeshKadam Heey, I did not have time to look at it yet, just checked and it works like a charm! Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Connection.java as it is

GetCommonConnections.java

```
public class GetCommonConnections implements JsonDeserializer<GetCommonConnections>, 
JsonSerializer<GetCommonConnections> {

    public TreeMap<Long, Connection> connectionTreeMap;

    public String success;

    public String error;

    @Override
    public GetCommonConnections deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        GetCommonConnections getCommonConnections = gson.fromJson(json, GetCommonConnections.class);
        getCommonConnections.connectionTreeMap = new TreeMap<>();

        JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        Set<String> keySet = jsonObject.keySet();
        Iterator<String> keyIterator = keySet.iterator();

        while (keyIterator.hasNext()) {

            String key = keyIterator.next();

            if (TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(key)) {

                getCommonConnections.connectionTreeMap.put(Long.valueOf(key),
                        gson.fromJson(jsonObject.get(key), Connection.class));
            }
        }

        return getCommonConnections;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(GetCommonConnections src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();

        Set<Long> longSet = src.connectionTreeMap.keySet();
        Iterator<Long> longIterator = longSet.iterator();

        while (longIterator.hasNext()) {

            Long key = longIterator.next();

            jsonObject.add(String.valueOf(key),
                    gson.toJsonTree(src.connectionTreeMap.get(key)));
        }

        jsonObject.addProperty("success", src.success);
        jsonObject.addProperty("error", src.error);

        return jsonObject;
    }
}
```

CustomGsonConverterFactory

```
public GsonConverterFactory createCustomGsonConverterFactory() {

        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();

        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(GetCommonConnections.class,
                new GetCommonConnections());

        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

        return GsonConverterFactory.create(gson);
    }
```

Build Retrofit as following -

```
public Retrofit buildRetrofit() {

    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("your base URL")
            .addConverterFactory(createCustomGsonConverterFactory())
            .build();
}
```

Code for testing if GetCommonConnections JsonDeserializer and JsonSerializer works or not -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String jsonResponseString = "{\n" +
                "   \"0\":{\n" +
                "      \"first_name\":\"Menno\",\n" +
                "      \"avatar\":\"[avatar here]\",\n" +
                "      \"updated_at\":\"2017-04-08 11:17:35\",\n" +
                "      \"id\":101\n" +
                "   },\n" +
                "   \"1\":{\n" +
                "      \"first_name\":\"Team\",\n" +
                "      \"avatar\":\"[avatar here]\",\n" +
                "      \"updated_at\":\"2017-11-01 11:00:18\",\n" +
                "      \"id\":102\n" +
                "   },\n" +
                "   \"success\":\"retrieve_common_connections_success\"\n" +
                "}";

        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(GetCommonConnections.class,
                new GetCommonConnections());
        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

        GetCommonConnections getCommonConnections = gson.fromJson(jsonResponseString, GetCommonConnections.class);

        Log.d("MainActivity", "-> " + gson.toJson(getCommonConnections));
    }
}
```

Also you this call everywhere -

```
Call<GetCommonConnections>
```